# Pair-wise similarity calculation between two batches without iteration?

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn, similarity

I have two 3D arrays. The first is of size `1000x1x5`, and the second is of size `1000x10x5`, where `1000` is the batch size.

I want to calculate the pairwise similarity between the `1x5` row vector and its corresponding 10 row vectors from batch B.

This can be done using sklearn https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.metrics.pairwise by iteration through the batch. My question is that **is it possible to do this without iteration**?

Comment: Is there a particular method within `pairwise` that you are solving for?

Comment: If your goal is to speed up computations, you could use `apply_along_axes` (see [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_over_axes.html#numpy.apply_over_axes))